# ServiceBusError: The messaging entity

Tags: node.js, azure, nestjs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using the `@azure/service-bus` library in NestJs. The code is working and I can send and receive messages. However, when I receive messages, I am getting the following error.

```
ServiceBusError: The messaging entity `'sb://[Namespace].servicebus.windows.net/test_topic.reply'` could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  TrackingId:40f1665b-7838-4e40-acbe-5d7472766844_G10, SystemTracker:[Namespace].servicebus.windows.net:test_topic.reply, Timestamp:2022-12-19T16:31:29
```

How can I create the `sb://[Namespace].servicebus.windows.net/test_topic.reply` in my account or is there any other way to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here when I use the following code, I am not getting any error.

code:

```
const { delay, ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage } = require("@azure/service-bus");

  

const  connectionString = "Connection String From The Portal "

const  topicName = "<Name OF TOPIC>";

const  subscriptionName = "<NAME OF SUBSCRIPTION YOU CREATED IN AZURE SERVICE  Bus>";

  
  

const  client = new  ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

  

const  receiver = client.createReceiver(topicName,subscriptionName);

  

const  messageProcessor = async (message) => {

    console.log(` message: ${message.body}`);

};

  

const  errorProcessor = async (err)=>{

    console.log(err);

};

  

receiver.subscribe({

    processMessage:messageProcessor,

    processError:errorProcessor

});
```

Output:

[image]

- Message Entities in the context of the Service Bus are Queues, Topics and Subscription make sure they are created prior to processing the messages

Refer this [MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#:%7E:text=the%20messaging%20entities%20that%20form%20the%20core%20of%20the%20messaging%20capabilities%20in%20service%20bus%20are%20queues,%20topics%20and%20subscriptions.) for service bus .